# Hibernate NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: hibernate, maven

I get the following error while I have hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar in the dependencies. What could be wrong?

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoadingException
```

EDIT:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ClassLoadingException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1132)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1402)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>`